# Can't update sql through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini");

$conn = new mysqli($settings[servername],$settings[username],$settings[password], $settings[dbname]);
$height = $_POST['heightFt'] * 12 + $_POST['heightIn'];
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
list($currentFName, $currentLName) = explode(",", $_COOKIE['user']);

}
$newFName = $_POST['fName'];
$newLName = $_POST['lName'];
$newAge = $_POST['age'];
$newWeight = $_POST['weight'];
$newHeight = $_POST['height'];
$newSex = $_POST['sex'];
$sql = "update $settings[userTable] set fName = $newFName, lName = $newLName, age = $newAge, weight = $newWeight, height = $newHeight, sex = $newSex where fName = $currentFName and lName = $currentLName";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
if(!$retval)
{
    die("Could not update data: " .  print_r($_POST) );
    //die("Could not update data: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "successful update";
```

This isn't working and I don't know how to troubleshoot it. 
with the code as is it shows 
`Array ( [fName] => Test [lName] => Testing [age] => 25 [weight] => 199 [sex] => male [heightFt] => 5 [heightIn] => 7 ) Could not update data: 1`

with

`//die("Could not update data: " .  print_r($_POST) );
        die("Could not update data: " . mysql_error());`

it shows

`Could not update data:`

is there anywhere that php shows errors. usually when something goes wrong in my code I just get a white screen and have to figure out the issue through trial and error with a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Enable debug mode in PHP. What stack are you running?

Comment: You seem to using two PHP extensions: your connection is made with the newer `mysqli` extension, but your query is made with the deprecated `mysql` extension. Probably you should migrate all of your code to use `mysqli`.

Comment: When you do get a statement submitted to the database, hopefully `$newFName` won't have a value of **`Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --`**.  [**Exploits of a Mom** https://xkcd.com/327/](https://xkcd.com/327/)  Reference: [**OWASP SQL Injection** https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing mysqli and mysql interface calls. That *doesn't* work.

We see a mysqli connection being created...

```
$conn = new mysqli(
```

But we see calls to `mysql_` interface function.

```
$retval = mysql_query(
```

Don't do that. That doesn't doesn't work. Use **`mysqli_`** functions.

So, fix that first.

---

For debugging SQL, echo out `$sql` before you submit it to the database. (Make sure the string you're sending is the SQL statement you want to execute.)

Also, incorporating potentially unsafe values (such as values of variables from a $_GET or $_POST) leads to **SQL Injection** vulnerabilities. Values incorporated into the text of a SQL statement must be properly escaped.  See `mysqli_real_escape_string`. But that's not sufficient to guarantee that code isn't still vulnerable to SQL Injection.

A better pattern is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.

---

This isn't right.

If `$newFName` is <kbd>Fred</kbd> and `$newLName` is <kbd>Flintstone</kbd>

Then this:

```
$sql = "update $settings[userTable] set fName = $newFName, lName = $newLName, ...";
```

or you might actually need to do this:

```
$sql = "update " . $settings[userTable] . " set fName = $newFName, lName = $newLName, ...";
```

evaluates to

```
 update mytable set fName = Fred, lName = Flintstone, ...
```

MySQL is going to balk at that, because string literals should be enclosed in single quotes:

```
 update mytable set fName = 'Fred', lName = 'Flintstone', ...
                            ^    ^          ^          ^
```

If `$newLName` is <kbd>O'Reilly</kbd>, MySQL is going to balk, he's going to see string literal `'O'` followed by something MySQL doesn't understand...

```
 update mytable set fName = 'Fred', lName = 'O'Reilly', ...
                                               ^^^^^^
```

To get that to run correctly, we need to *escape* that single quote inside the value with another single quote, so our SQL statement looks like this:

```
 update mytable set fName = 'Fred', lName = 'O''Reilly', ...
                                              ^^
```

The two single quotes inside the string literal are interpreted (by MySQL) as a one single quote. The value that will be stored in the column (assuming the statement succeeds of course), will be what we wanted: <kbd>O'Reilly</kbd>

You could muck with escaping the values, but a *much better* pattern is prepared statements with bind placeholders...

```
 $sql = "update mytable set fName= ? ,lName = ?, ... ";

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("ss",$newFName,$newLName);
 $stmt->execute();
```

REFERENCE: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation. I'm mostly self teaching so that's the reason for my mistakes. Are you saying I don't have to worry about sql injection with prepared statements?

Comment: @dlrdlrdlr: Yes, sort of. It's not really the prepared statements that protect you from SQL Injection. It's the **bind placeholders** in the statement. Notice that in the example I showed in my answer, the SQL string is a *static* string. There are no variable values being incorporated into it, there's no way for `$sql` to contain anything but that static string. The values supplied through bind parameters do not become part of the SQL text. There is no way that the value can be interpreted as part of the SQL text, they are just *values*. So, yes, that's the best you can do to prevent...

Comment: (cont.) SQL Injection vulnerabilities. (We will note that the MySQL library may actually re-write the statement to include the values in the text, if server side prepared statements is not enabled. But at that point, it's the responsibility of the MySQL library routines to do this correctly, without introducing SQL injection. (This isn't to say that there's absolutely 100% no possibility of a vulnerability. For example, if there's a characterset translation going on, and some odd duck multibyte characters get translated to a single quote. But that vulnerability is *much* harder to exploit.